# c# SqlGeography latitude & longitude unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, sqlgeography

Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ToString has unexpected behavior.

Take a look at my unit test:

```
 latitude = 40.584474F;
 longitude = -111.633491F;
 var location = SqlGeography.Point( latitude, longitude, 4326 );
 var point = location.ToString();
```

At this point, the variable point has a value of:
POINT (-111.63349151611328 40.58447265625)

As you can see, latitude and longitude have been swapped from the norm.

This is from a nuget package downloaded today. (v11.0.2)

**Clarification:** Object values are correct but `ToString()` is producing a format which is not appropriate to SQL Server itself, even though this is a SQLServer specific class in my opinion.

Update 2: This is not a duplicate because it is different from the question with a similar title, since this is about a .NET class (Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ToString), rather than SQL Server itself.

Comment: Not a duplicate for: A bug in SQL Geography POINT Lat, Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server 12 will accept: geography::Point(47.65100, -122.3490, 4326). To produce the string that would be acceptable to SQL Server:

```
var point = ColValue as SqlGeography;
if (point != null)
return "geography::Point(" + point.Lat + ", " + point.Long + ", 4326)";
```

Answer (score 3):

The latitude and longitude have not been swapped. It's just that the `Point()` constructor accepts the longitude after latitude, but in `ToString()` longitude is printed before latitude.

Print the values `location.Lat` and `location.Long` to know for sure.

Comment: @Gunnar: It can't be called a bug as the values are just fine. It, however, is a little poorly designed API that swaps the order of variables and leads to confusion.

Comment: displayName, That's a design bug at least.  Logically, the ToString of a class in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types should naturally produce the string that would be acceptable to SQL Server. SQL Server will accept:
geography::Point(47.65100, -122.3490, 4326)

If a different format is needed for some edge case, the function should make that clear, e.g. AsWGS84() or PointLongLat()

Comment: 30+ years of software engineering experience tells me that designs can have bugs, same as code. In fact, design bugs are far more prevalent and important. A bug is any problem. A code bug = "not working as designed", while design bug = "not designed to meet requirements" and a specification bug = "not specified to meet user needs".  Good bug tracking systems support these types of issues. Your definition is too narrow for industry best practices.